# Factors in a multi-factor design

Tags: experiment-design, nested-models

I have trouble distinguishing between a factor and a replicate. For instance, in my class notes, there is a question:

*To study the variability in CO2 emission rate by global regions 4 countries: US, Britain, India, and Australia were chosen. From each country, 3 major cities were chosen and the emission rates for each month for the year 2019 were collected.*

The notes say this is a nested model with two factors, countries and cities. And the replicates are 12 months of 2019.

I was wondering why the months cannot be a factor? In that case, we will have three factors with cities nested in counties and months crossed with the combination of the countries and cities, so we will have a cross-nested model with the number of replicates equals 1.

Another example in the notes:

*The GPA comparison of four popular majors, biology, business, engineering, and psychology, between males and females is of interest.  For 6 semesters, the average GPA of each of these majors for male and female students was computed.*

The notes say it is a cross model with two factors, majors and genders. The replicates are semesters. So same question, why the semesters cannot be a factor here?

Thanks!